# Problem increasing WCF service endpoint size configuration

Tags: wcf

I have an asp.net project that was hosting a WCF service (via the wcf file exposure technique for IIS) that was put together around 10 years ago. There is an operation on the service that retrieves content that is greater than the default 75K limit. The service configuration (in web.config) property on the binding was adjusted to be larger than the default and was working ok. The ASP.NET project was upgraded in VS2017/2019 - and (I assume) the project was adjusted (somehow). The service operation described above no longer works. I did a lot of investigation and all solutions were handled (which makes sense as the original version of the project was working). I even went through the process of building a new web.config with minimal configuration and still did not work. I also adjusted the service to include the Configure operation that could be used to configure the endpoint configuration in code. It also did not work. For this I have the following:

```
    public static void Configure(ServiceConfiguration config)
    {            
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize  = int.MaxValue;
        binding.MaxBufferSize           = int.MaxValue;
        binding.MaxBufferPoolSize       = int.MaxValue;

        binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = true;

        binding.ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
        {
            MaxStringContentLength  = int.MaxValue,
            MaxDepth                = int.MaxValue,
            MaxArrayLength          = int.MaxValue,
            MaxBytesPerRead         = int.MaxValue,
            MaxNameTableCharCount   = int.MaxValue
        };

        var endpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(
            ContractDescription.GetContract(
                    typeof(IAuthenticateServicePack)),binding,new 
         EndpointAddress("http://localhost:49437/WCFSevices/AuthenticateServicePack.svc"));

        //MyEndpointBehavior Behavior = new MyEndpointBehavior();
        //endpoint.Behaviors.Add(Behavior);

        config.AddServiceEndpoint(endpoint);
    }
```

The web.config definitions is the following

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" 
/>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServicePack.ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="500" maxConcurrentSessions="500" 
/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>      
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <clear />

    <binding name="myBindingForBigArrays" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
transferMode="Buffered">
      <readerQuotas 
        maxDepth="32" 
        maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
        maxNameTableCharCount="10000"             
      />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service name="Lapp.WebAdmin.Mvc.WCFSevices.AuthenticateServicePack" 
behaviorConfiguration="ServicePack.ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
bindingConfiguration="myBindingForBigArrays" 
contract="Lapp.WebAdmin.Mvc.WCFSevices.IAuthenticateServicePack" />

    <host>
      <timeouts closeTimeout="00:01:00" />
    </host>

     </service>
   </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

For some reason - the updated asp.net project does not seem to be handling the WCF service endpoint configuration. Has anyone run into this issue?

Note: I can test the older version of the service and is working properly -- and reviewing the old config with the new -- cannot identify any modification that would appear to be causing the new not to use the size limit settings.

Comment: Here are two configurations of the basichttpbinding, how can I determine which configuration works. You say that the WCF service is hosted in an Asp.net project. But I don’t see the ServiceHost Class. If it exists. Please post the related code snippets.
Is this project a WCF service application project template?
Only when we find the configuration used by the Service Host object can our modified configuration take effect.
Please post the complete project structure and more information about the WCF service

Comment: As I stated -- neither works -- and they are not different - if you read the posting you would understand it is the same definition applied via an asp.net web.config configuration and a code based definition ---

As I stated this is a WCF service hosted within an ASP.NET project - it uses svc configuraiton -- i.e. IIS is managing the hosting of the service

Comment: Could it be an issue with IIS?  IIS has limits on the amount of data that will be sent, so even if WCF is working as expected (i.e., the right binding is picked up), IIS could be preventing it.  What error(s) and/or behavior are you seeing? "Not working" is very vague.

Comment: Ok --  deployed the service to a new server -- and appears to be working ok. So this looks to be an issue with IIS as @Tim stated. This question can be closed.